# Update ArcPy version to avoid AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetClassNames'?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, attributeerror, error-000840

This is probably the answer to my previous question: [Listing Elements or Datasets of Layer gives ERROR 000840 value is not Feature Layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28532/list-elements-or-datasets-of-a-given-layer).

The version of arcpy that I am using does not include GetNAClassNames

> naClasses = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(serviceAreaLayer)

**AttributeError**: `'module' object has no attribute 'GetClassNames'`

According to this [help topic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/GetNAClassNames/01mr00000004000000/), GetNAClassNames is in ArcGIS 10.1. Why is it not in my version?

Comment: What version of ESRI products are you using? Some companies/organizations are behind because of testing and licensing requirements.

Comment: You're not on 10.1, plain and simple. It's only been out for a couple of weeks.

Comment: You are right. I checked my version and it is 10.0.2414. But now, there is no way for me to get that ClassNames of the service area layers?? I need to select the Polygons (layer) which is inside the Service Area layer.

Answer (score 1):

If your company is current on esri maintenance, 10.1 is available for download. The license manager will have to be updated, not a difficult task. The install is straight forward. Our only issue so far is ArcINFO Workstation 9.0 no longer talks with a 10.1 LM.

Comment: Caution: some companies/organizations restrict your ability to install or upgrade software. You may need to make a request to your IT help desk.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have shown us of your code and error there seems to be a mismatch.

You are trying to call `arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames()` and yet the error says:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetClassNames'

and not:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetNAClassNames'

I think you are either looking at a line of code that is not responsible for the error, and recommend that you check/present the precise code snippet that produces your error.